# serialize a disabled textbox value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am serializing a form with jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnsubmit", function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/RiskScore",
    type: "post",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        $('.content-wrap').html(result);
    }
  });
});
```

And one of my textboxes is BMI and counts the bmi out of two other textboxes. I don't want anyone to be able to change the value of the textbox and thats why i have disabled it. The problem is that when it is disabled the serializing method above works but it can't find the BMI textbox and its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution :)

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnsubmit", function () {
$("#PersonBMI").removeAttr('disabled');
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/RiskScore",
    type: "post",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        $('.content-wrap').html(result);
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to have a hidden value with the BMI this way it will get picked up by serialization.

Also, if you want to display the value, you can simply display it in a `<div>` or `<span>` or just as a string.